# sort hex numbers from the command line?

Tags: windows, linux, command-line, cygwin, gnuwin32

i'm looking for ways to sort a file of hex numbers
like

```
C3
A2
3F
```

From the command line

linux solutions are welcome, though i'll be using windows and cygwin or gnuwin32.

Comment: Are we to assume from your example that all numbers have 2 digits and do not use lower case?

Comment: @Dipstick  if you have a solution that assumes that, then that's still of interest.  But regarding upper/lower case, I just found this http://slaptijack.com/system-administration/how-do-i-convert-to-uppercase-on-the-command-line/  $ echo waslowercase | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'

Comment: `sort -f` does case-insensitive sorting, eliminating the need for passing your input through another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matt@netbook:~$ sort
C3
A2
3F
^D
3F
A2
C3
```

Of course you can pipe to this command, or use any of it's [options](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/) also.

---

Comment: can you please include a full example so I can see it doing hex? 'cos I don't see a hex option. And is it doing hex or ascii? i'm not sure if they'd work out equivalent

Comment: yeah looks like no options required.  And the ascii sort works for hex!

Comment: Ascii sort works for hex because numerals come immediately before the capital letters. If this answer were any more specific, it would lose its generality ;) I will add however, that you must be careful with hex numbers of differing lengths, but that's a separate question.